# Efficient way to find price momentum in python: averaging last n entries of a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**I'm defining price momentum** is an average of the given stock’s momentum over the past *n* days.

Momentum, in turn, is a classification: each day is labeled 1 if closing price that day is higher than the day before, and −1 if the price is lower than the day before.

I have stock change percentages as follows:

```
df['close in percent'] = np.array([0.27772152, 1.05468772, 
                                   0.124156 , -0.39298394, 
                                   0.56415267,  1.67812005])

momentum = df['close in percent'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else -1).values
```

`Momentum` should be: `[1,1,1,-1,1,1]`.

So if I'm finding the average momentum for the last **n = 3 days**, I want my price momentum to be:

```
Price_momentum = [Nan, Nan, 1, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3]
```

I managed to use the following code to get it working, but this is extremely slow (the dataset is 5000+ rows and it takes 10 min to execute).

```
for i in range(3,len(df)+1,1):
    data = np.array(momentum[i-3:i])
    df['3_day_momentum'].iloc[i-1]=data.mean()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) object:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['close_in_percent'] = np.array([0.27772152, 1.05468772, 
                                   0.124156 , -0.39298394, 
                                   0.56415267,  1.67812005])
df['momentum'] = np.where(df['close_in_percent'] > 0, 1, -1)
df['3_day_momentum'] = df.momentum.rolling(3).mean()
```

Here, `np.where` is an alternative to `apply()`, which is generally slow and should be used as a last resort.

```
   close_in_percent  momentum  3_day_momentum
0            0.2777         1             NaN
1            1.0547         1             NaN
2            0.1242         1          1.0000
3           -0.3930        -1          0.3333
4            0.5642         1          0.3333
5            1.6781         1          0.3333
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `np.where` + `pd.Rolling.mean` -

```
s = df['close in percent']
pd.Series(np.where(s > 0, 1, -1)).rolling(3).mean()

0         NaN
1         NaN
2    1.000000
3    0.333333
4    0.333333
5    0.333333
dtype: float64
```

---

For v0.17 or below, there's also `rolling_mean` which works with arrays directly.

```
pd.rolling_mean(np.where(s > 0, 1, -1), window=3)
array([        nan,         nan,  1.        ,  0.33333333,  0.33333333,
        0.33333333])
```

Comment: We'll just have to agree to agree

Comment: @BradSolomon Kudos, you were 11 seconds faster ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Those rolling averages are basically uniform filtered values. Hence, we can use [`SciPy's uniform filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter1d.html) -

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import uniform_filter1d

def rolling_mean(ar, W=3):
    hW = (W-1)//2
    out = uniform_filter1d(momentum.astype(float), size=W, origin=hW)
    out[:W-1] = np.nan
    return out

momentum = 2*(df['close in percent'] > 0) - 1
df['out'] = rolling_mean(momentum, W=3)
```

#### Benchmarking

Timing `pandas.rolling` and `SciPy's uniform filter` -

```
In [463]: df = pd.DataFrame({'close in percent':np.random.randn(1000000)})

In [464]: df['momentum'] = np.where(df['close in percent'] > 0, 1, -1)

In [465]: momentum = 2*(df['close in percent'] > 0) - 1

# From @Brad Solomon's soln
In [466]: %timeit df['3_day_momentum'] = df.momentum.rolling(3).mean()
10 loops, best of 3: 27.3 ms per loop

# SciPy's uniform filter
In [467]: %timeit df['3_day_momentum_out'] = rolling_mean(momentum, W=3)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.69 ms per loop
```

Comment: Faster and over my head, as usual.  What is `origin` (=1) doing here?  I cannot infer from the docs.

Comment: @BradSolomon Essentially pads at the start with reflected elements of length `W-1`. So, if `a = [1,2,3,4]`, then `a_pad = [2,1,1,2,3,4]` and then computes sliding windowed averages on `a_pad`. With `origin = -1`, the padding would be at other end. With `origin = 0`, it would be padding of one each on both ends.