# How to compare CSV column data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, dataframe

I have a huge CSV file with 2 relevant columns. Time and speed. The data got created while driving a car.

Now, I want to compare some values of the speed column in order to conclude if the car is accelerating or getting slower and put it in a new dataframe "accelerating".

For example:

```
if speed (row 1) < speed (row2) car is accelerating.
```

Comment: Why don't you use the numpy `diff` function to get the gradient of speed? If the time intervals are uniform then it's the accurate acceleration, if not then it still shows if the car is accelerating or decelerating.

Comment: Do you mean if speed (**row** 1) < speed (**row** 2) ?

Comment: yea row 1 and row 2 sorry

Comment: are you familiar with https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html ?

Comment: not really. i will check it

Comment: this would also be useful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244097/efficient-way-to-find-price-momentum-in-python-averaging-last-n-entries-of-a-co

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`pd.Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) to create a Boolean series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'speed': [1.41, 5.341, 10.3412, 3.341, 456.432]})

df['accelerating'] = df['speed'].diff() > 0

print(df)

      speed accelerating
0    1.4100        False
1    5.3410         True
2   10.3412         True
3    3.3410        False
4  456.4320         True
```

Then filtering for accelerating rows is trivial:

```
df_acc = df[df['accelerating']]

print(df_acc)

      speed accelerating
1    5.3410         True
2   10.3412         True
4  456.4320         True
```

The above is the Pandorable shorthand for `df_acc = df.loc[df['accelerating'] == True]`.

Comment: lol my edit make it more pandonic bro. using your syntax as it is correct, but more dangerous

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ, Ha, that's an opinion. In my view, it's very natural to index a dataframe with a Boolean series directly. Why would it be more dangerous?

Comment: :) no worries thats fine with me as well

Comment: Ugh, it's not "pandonic" or "pandorable". The maintainers uses "pandaic", can we stick to that please

Comment: @coldspeed, No need to open a Pandora's box!

Comment: @jpp you seem very talented and helpful. I would have another question. Can I contact you anywhere? :)

Comment: @Michelle, Unfortunately, I'm only available on SO for programming-related questions. You can try here, or ping me elsewhere on a question I've answered.

Comment: @jpp I would like to analyse some pattern in my data. For example: driving torwards a traffic light: braking, waiting, and accerlerating again:  If speed < 30 & accelerating == false & speed.isin (0) (for braking and waiting) & speed > 5 & accerlerating == true (for accelerating again). how can i put this in one dataframe, cause there are some contradictory arguments :s

Comment: @Michelle, Sorry, your question seems far too broad. You need to learn about Pandas (I recommend the [official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html)), have a go yourself, check if any other questions on SO help you, then come back and [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if still stuck. Unfortunately, there's no shortcut!